# How do I make the code print the first line from the text file?

Tags: c++

This is a simple code that searches a txt file for the string `"G for Grapes"` and prints each line as it goes. The file has the following text in it

1. A for Apple
2. B for Ball
3. C for Cat
4. D for Duck
5. E for Elephant
6. F for Football
7. G for Grapes

But when the loop for reading it runs, It starts from **B** instead of **A**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    string line;
    string finD = "G for Grapes";

    fin.open("sample.txt");

    getline(fin, line);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(fin, line); i++)
    {
        cout << line << endl;

        if (line.find(finD, 0) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "\n Fount it!\n In line no# " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    
    fin.close();

    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `getline` every iteration of your `for` loop, including the first one.

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
getline(fin, line);  // reads first line
    
for (unsigned int i = 1; getline(fin, line); i++)  // reads second line
{
   cout << line << endl;  // prints second line
```

You need to simply remove the call to `getline` that is outside the `for` loop, otherwise you are ignoring the first line, and not printing it out.